# Migrate RequestMapping from older spring to spring 5 unable to replace /**/ at the beginning

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, migration

I'm having issues migrating a Java application from 14 to 17 due to the upgrade on spring to version 5. The problem I have is the following:

I have a controller with `@RequestMapping(value = "/**/{[something:[^.]*}")`

The application seems to work just fine on localhost, however some paths are built wrongly on the server and some JUnits are failing, throwing: `org.springframework.web.util.pattern.PatternParseException: No more pattern data allowed after {*...} or ** pattern element`. Reading the spring docs here https://spring.io/blog/2020/06/30/url-matching-with-pathpattern-in-spring-mvc/ I discovered we cannot use anymore `/**/` at the beginning, and it's only allowed at the end.

Is there any way to still keep the same behavior and replace ** at the beginning with something equivalent? I leave below the docs for the AntPathMatcher, since there is a difference between * and ** and I'm using `spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ANT_PATH_MATCHER` to still use the AntPathMatcher.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html

And I've also looked at the following samples with no success.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-5-mvc-url-matching

Any help/suggestion/advice is welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the docs it says

> Note: a pattern and a path must both be absolute or must both be relative in order for the two to match. Therefore, it is recommended that users of this implementation to sanitize patterns in order to prefix them with "/" as it makes sense in the context in which they're used.

The path in your request mapping is absolute, please check if the failing test are accessing the controller by a relative route or absolute route.